# What is the record for winning a Formula 1 race by leading least number of laps?

Tags: trivia, records, formula-1

What is the record for winning a Formula 1 race by a driver who has lead the least number of laps in that race?

For example: if one driver has been in position 1 for the entire race but on the last lap had an engine failure such that the driver in position 2 won the race without actually leading the race for any laps.

Has this ever happened? If not that what is the minimum number?

Comment: The lead laps is only defined when the driver crosses the line right? So, if he takes the win on last lap wouldn't be 0 laps lead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been cases where a driver won without leading a single lap (mostly due to post-race disqualifications), and there have been cases where a driver took the lead on the last lap, of which my favourite was the [2011 Canadian Grand Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Canadian_Grand_Prix) win by Jenson Button.

List of drivers who won without leading [(source)](http://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/victoire/sans-tour-en-tete.aspx):
[image: WWL]

List of drivers who won after leading only one lap [(source)](http://www.statsf1.com/en/statistiques/pilote/victoire/dernier-tour.aspx):

[image: LL1]